# How to add more than one plan inside Razorpay Subscription?

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway, strip, razorpay

I have multiple plans and want to implement Razorpay for Payment.
I tested it as well, but I was able to add only one plan to a subscription.

Is there any way to add more than one plan to a single Razorpay subscription?

Or should I switch to Strip or any other platform for this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I don't think Razorpay has an option to add multiple plans in a single subscription of different types. (The same plan can be added multiple times in a subscription though)

Why not consider using - [charge_at_will or Emandate](https://razorpay.com/e-mandate/)

Comment: @AmitKadam anytime. Do let me know if you need anything while integrating with Razorpay.